# Spring Data / MongoDB: Copy a single document from one collection to another in one go

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How to copy a single document from one collection to anther `in one go` with Spring Data?

Right now, I am finding the document by id and save it to another collection. But thats 2 steps.

Is there anything like `findAndCopy` kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Aggregation framework as shown below.

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = match(Criteria.where("somekey").is("someValue"));

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project().andExpression("someKey").as("Key")
        .andExpression("otherKey").as("SomeOtherKey");

OutOperation outOperation = out("New_Collection_Name");
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, projectionOperation, outOperation);

mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Existing_Collection_Name", ResultClass.class);
```

Here ResultClass should be defined based on fields that you use in projection.

If you want to write all the fields to new collection(and not only few), then you can remove projection operation in the above pipeline. ResultClass in this case will be same same as your Document(input) class

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot!